# Facebook LoginButton inside Dialog

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-3.0

I'm working with Facebook SDK. I'm adding Facebook LoginButton inside a Dialog, but when I click it, my request doesn't work.

public class StartsFragment extends Fragment {

```
ClassicButton classicButton;
Dialog dialog;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.starts_fragment, container, false);

    final Fragment startsFragment;
    startsFragment = this;

    Button joinUs = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.joinus);
    joinUs.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            dialog = new Dialog(getActivity(), R.style.UserLoginRegisterDialog);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.login_dialog_fragment);

            LoginButton lb = (LoginButton) dialog.findViewById(R.id.authButton);
            lb.setFragment(getParentFragment());
            lb.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("email","user_birthday"));

            dialog.show();
               dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
});
return view;
}
```

And I See my log,

```
{Session state:OPENING, token:{AccessToken token:ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED permissions:[]}, appId:******}
```

Why I couldn't see my permission request ? And why response every time null session?

Best regards,

Comment: Did you override the onActivityResult method in your parentFragment to call through to the session's onActivityResult?

Comment: No, I' dont override parentFragment but when I try to override in Fragment class, again my permission is goes to null ({Session state:OPENING, token:{AccessToken token:ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED permissions:[]}, ) and comes to message like this RequestCode:64206. 

Normally I'm waiting work for My Parent FragmentActivity. I did override onActivityResult there.

Comment: The way that Facebook login (including the login button) works is that it starts a new activity to actually do the login, and then calls finishWithResult so it will return to your calling activity. When you call setFragment on the LoginButton with a fragment, it's telling the SDK to use that fragment's startActivityForResult to start the login activity, and the result goes back via onActivityResult. You MUST override the onActivityResult method in whichever fragment or activity that's calling login.